# Export not displayed in Grocery Crud Datatables Theme

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have enabled `datatables` theme of grocery crud, but can't seem to get the Export button. Is there an option to set/make the Export Button visible for DataTables theme? Even in the example [here](https://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/render) the datatable theme doesn't seem to have the Export button while the flexigrid button has the export button. How to display the Export button for grocery crud datatable theme?

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Seemed to be an issue with my application `css` Resolved the issue by modifying application css. Though the Export Button still seem to be not functional as it has some embed code that requires flash player enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this code in local machine and its seems to be working fine. There might be missing image issue thats way you are not getting export button. Please copy all image

**from**

```
assets\grocery_crud\themes\flexigrid\css\images
```

**to**

```
assets\grocery_crud\themes\datatables\css\images
```

Let me know if it not works.